# How to load Figaro ENV variable in GemFiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, gemfile

I use Figaro for ENV configuration for my rails app.

application.yml

```
LOG_RAILS_CALLBACKS: "true"
```

and I have GemFile.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rails-callback_log", require: (ENV['LOG_RAILS_CALLBACKS'] == 'true')
end
```

But this seems not working.

How can I get access to ENV variable in GemFile?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this locally.

If you create a real env variable, it works:

`export LOG_RAILS_CALLBACKS=true`

My guess is that Figaro is not yet loaded, I've tried to load it explicitly but still doesn't work:

`(require 'figaro' && ::Figaro.require_keys("LOG_RAILS_CALLBACKS")`

I would try to either use a real ENV variable, or do it elsewhere:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rails-callback_log"
end
```

And in your `development.rb` or `test.rb`:

`require 'rails-callback_log' if ENV['LOG_RAILS_CALLBACKS'] == 'true'`